# Harmony as a state usage

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Can we say `works in harmony with other groups`. I understand the adjective is `harmonious` and all what I found in web is using as harmony as a name [here](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/harmony). Can we use it to express **state**. Further, is `In accordance with` a good replacement? What about 'In concord with'?

Comment: "In harmony" I could understand, but "in a harmony" is a no-go.

Comment: @RegDwigнt That was big mistake, thanks for the notification

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are asking. What's the problem with a nice word like *harmony*? For one thing, *in accordance with* has nothing to do with *harmony*, and *in concord with* does not have the same simple and direct effect as *in harmony with*. The phrase *in harmony with* is an idiomatic expression in itself: *in harmony with nature*. http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+harmony

Comment: You could look at a better set of examples than what you found. Search for "in harmony with".

Comment: @Hawk That was **a** big mistake

Comment: @kris Thanks for the explanation. Indeed this is just what I wanted to know, that this nice idiomatic expression is used. I'm not a native speaker. You may extend your comment to answer :)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth lol, you are very fast :). cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can say that *someone works in harmony with other groups*.

**in harmony** (with someone or something) is an idiom.

> [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+harmony): **2.** *Fig*. agreeable or compatible with someone or something. (*Typically: **be** ~; **get** ~.)
> *This is in complete harmony with our earlier discussions*.
> *Fred's position is quite clear. What you have said is not in harmony with Fred*.

More than the technical meaning in dictionaries, the expression has a nice ring to it brought about by usage.

> Modernity thus coincides with nostalgia for a mode of existence in which one was in harmony with one's surroundings.

(Henry Weinfield)

> Our responsibility as human beings in creation is to strive for balance and to live in harmony with each other and with all living things.

(Blaser, et al.)

> The Chinese and the Indian traditions speak about living in harmony with the universe. This supposes that the universe itself is functioning harmoniously. Anyone who lives in harmony with the universe – human and material – is living in peace …

(Michael Amaladoss )